# Detect the threads that finish in order

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I have the following multethreaded code

```
class My_Thread extends Thread {

    public function run() {

        /* ... */
        // The time it takes to execut the code is different for each thread
    }
}

// Create a array
$threads = array();


/* *** STEP 1 *** */
//Initiate Miltiple Threads
foreach ( range("A", "B") as $i ) {
    $threads[] = new My_Thread($i);
}


/* *** STEP 2 *** */
// Start The Threads
foreach ($threads as $thread) {
    $thread->start(); // Thread A starts before thread B, and it takes more time to finish
}


/* *** STEP 3 *** */
// Process the threads
foreach ($threads as $thread) {
    if ($thread->join()) {
        /* ... Do Something ... */
    }
}
```

To explain the code quickly:

Step 1: I am creating two threads, A and B

Step 2: Thread A is started first, and takes longer time to finish than thread B.

Step 3: Then, I am waiting for each thread to finish, starting with thread A.

Now, the problem is in Step 3. As I loop through the threads, I have to wait for thread A to finish in order to do further processig, yet, thread B is waiting in idle state, because it takes shorter time to finish, and will not be processed unless thread A is processed in step 3. *It is not guaranteed that thread A will take longer time, so I have to write a generic solution.*

How can I ensure that step 3 processes whichever thread that is finished first? In other words, is there something like this pseudo code?

```
/* *** STEP 3 *** */
// Do the following for all threads in the $threads array, FIRST COME FIRST SERVE
// If the thread finished STEP 2, then immediately process it.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Remove join and try to print something in run function

Comment: When finished, your threads should emit their results to a queue, where they can be picked up by other code. This is basically a producer/consumer setup. Similarly, It should pick up its new job from a similar queue, so it doesn't sit idle. That said, sometimes it makes more sense to use a thread pool instead of reinventing the wheel. Just check the docs for available tools in addition to the plain `Thread` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, a `Thread` represents an *execution context*.

What you need to do is think of the context, and the data separately ...

```
<?php
class Test extends Thread {

    public function __construct(Volatile $queue, $value) {
        $this->queue = $queue;
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function run() {
        $data = strlen(
            file_get_contents("http://www.google.co.uk/?q={$this->value}"));

        usleep(mt_rand(10000, 20000));

        $this->queue->synchronized(function($queue, $value, $data) {
            $queue[] = (array) [
                $value => $data
            ];
            $queue->notify();
        }, $this->queue, $this->value, $data);
    }

    private $queue;
    private $value;
}

$chars = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"];
$queue = new Volatile();
$tests = [];

for ($test = 0; $test < 10; $test++) {
    $tests[$test] = new Test($queue, $chars[$test]);
    $tests[$test]->start();
}

$test = 0;

while (($next = $queue->synchronized(function() use($queue, &$test) {
    /* guard infinite loop */
    if (++$test > 10)
        return false;

    /* predicated wait for data */
    while (!count($queue))
        $queue->wait();

    /* return next item */
    return $queue->shift();
}))) {
    var_dump($next);
}

foreach ($tests as $thread)
    $thread->join();
?>
```

*The code above is for pthreads v3, PHP7, which is the best version available, and the recommended version to use for new projects.*

The guts of the solution are contained in `Test::run` and the while loop in the main context.

```
$data = strlen(
    file_get_contents("http://www.google.co.uk/?q={$this->value}"));

usleep(mt_rand(10000, 20000));
```

This was intended to fetch some garbage from google, it so happens that the response times are so consistent that I had to add `usleep`, only so that you can see that order doesn't matter if done correctly.

*You should never use `usleep` in real world multi-threaded code.*

```
$this->queue->synchronized(function($queue, $value, $data) {
    $queue[] = (array) [
        $value => $data
    ];
    $queue->notify();
}, $this->queue, $this->value, $data);
```

Having generated some data, each `Test` synchronizes with the queue, appends some data to it, and sends notification to any context currently waiting.

Meanwhile, this is going on:

```
$test = 0;

while (($next = $queue->synchronized(function() use($queue, &$test) {
    /* guard infinite loop */
    if (++$test > 10)
        return false;

    /* predicated wait for data */
    while (!count($queue))
        $queue->wait();

    /* return next item */
    return $queue->shift();
}))) {
    var_dump($next);
}
```

The main context synchronizes with the queue, while in the synchronized block it guards against infinite loops (since we know how much data is coming), then if there is no data in the queue, it will wait for some to become available. Finally returning the first item in the queue to the main context.

The above code will output something like:

```
array(1) {
  ["I"]=>
  int(188965)
}
array(1) {
  ["B"]=>
  int(188977)
}
array(1) {
  ["C"]=>
  int(188921)
}
array(1) {
  ["F"]=>
  int(188962)
}
array(1) {
  ["J"]=>
  int(188954)
}
array(1) {
  ["A"]=>
  int(188912)
}
array(1) {
  ["E"]=>
  int(188929)
}
array(1) {
  ["G"]=>
  int(188941)
}
array(1) {
  ["D"]=>
  int(188946)
}
array(1) {
  ["H"]=>
  int(188929)
}
```

The key thing here is that the context and the data are separate concerns.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will have to test it, but I have PHP 5.3, and since I use XAMPP, I have to wait for them to release PHP 7, which should be soon.